# Gitlab-git-http-server not working

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, gitlab, unicorn, sidekiq, ubuntu-server

Hi I'm trying to clone a remote repository to another remote repository but I'm getting errors trying to do so. i have figured out that Gitlab Unicorn and Sidekiq are not running so that's my issue. Here is the error I get when trying too start gitlab service:

```
sudo service gitlab restart
Starting GitLab Unicorn
Starting GitLab Sidekiq
Starting gitlab-git-http-server
/etc/init.d/gitlab: 223: /etc/init.d/gitlab: bin/web: not found
/etc/init.d/gitlab: 230: /etc/init.d/gitlab: bin/background_jobs: not found
..............................Waited 30s for the processes to write their pids, something probably went wrong.
```

Comment: I think I need to add stuff to bin/web and bin/background_jobs but I don't know what.

Comment: Are you using omnibus or source installation?